# Composer: required dependency conflict And version stability

Tags: php, github, composer-php, package

I have package **PACK-A**, which is require by other packages (**PACK-X**,**PACK-Y**,**PACK-Z)**.

I include all those packages in my main project PROJ-FUN.

Those packages (**PACK-X**,**PACK-Y**,**PACK-Z**) require version "~1.0.0" from PACK-A.

Now i clone PACK-A to a new repository with version "0.10.29" and now i try to require PACK-A in the project but i have the following error :

***Problem 1***

- VENDOR/PACK-X v1.1.1 requires VENDOR/PACK-A ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by 
  VENDOR/PACK-X[v1.0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or
  minimum-stability.
- ......
- ......
- Installation request for VENDOR/PACK-X ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by
  VENDOR/PACK-X[v1.1.1].

I try do the following but in vain :

- "VENDOR/PACK-A": "0.10.29 as 1.1.2" .
- "VENDOR/PACK-A": "dev-master" .
- "VENDOR/PACK-A": "@DEV" .
- Set minimum stability to dev.
- Ignore platform Requirement.

My Project JSON :

```
{
"name": "VENDOR/fun-project",
"description": "VENDOR/FUN APPLICAION",
"license": "proprietary",
"prefer-stable": "true",
"require": {
    "VENDOR/PACK-A": "0.10.29 as 1.1.2@dev",
    "VENDOR/PACK-X": "^1.1",
    "VENDOR/PACK-Y": "^1.1",
    "VENDOR/PACK-Z": "^1.1"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "discard-changes": "true"
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:VENDOR/PACK-A"
}]
```

}

PACK-XYZ JSON :

```
{
    "name": "VENDOR / PACK - X",
    "description": "",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "VENDOR / PACK - A": "~1.0.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.1.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/VENDOR/PACK-A.git"
    }]
}
```

Any one could help how to solve this ? 
Thank you in advance.

** References :**

- http://webtips.krajee.com/setting-composer-minimum-stability-application/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md
- [Can I override a composer.json dependency to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859285/can-i-override-a-composer-json-dependency-to-remove-it)
- [It's possible ignore child dependency in Composer config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637657/its-possible-ignore-child-dependency-in-composer-config)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all of your projects

- `vendor/pack-x`
- `vendor/pack-y`
- `vendor/pack-z`

depend on

- `vendor/pack-a:~1.0.0`

The `~` operator used here allows to install `vendor/pack-a` in any version equal to or greater than `1.0.0` and less than `1.1.0`.

Furthermore, your project

- `vendor/fun-project`

requires all of

- `vendor/pack-x`
- `vendor/pack-y`
- `vendor/pack-z`

and additionally

- `vendor/pack-a:0.10.29 as 1.1.2@dev`

However, `1.1.2@dev` clearly conflicts with the earlier version requirement of `~1.0.0`.

Try adjusting your inline alias for `vendor/fun-project` to:

- `vendor/pack-a:0.10.29 as 1.0.99`

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias
- http://semver.org

Comment: I have no control over PACKs X Y Z , or lets say i can't update them right now ,

Comment: So how does adjusting your requirement in `vendor/fun-project` work for you?

Comment: it's work only with if i use old vendor pack-a with version "^1.0.2" , if i change the repo URL to the new one with version "0.10.29" as "1.0.2" or even as "1.0.99" a lot of dependency start to fail.